# How to combine regions of a geojson map

Tags: python, dictionary, geojson, topology

I am working with map data - using a .geojson of zip codes. I'd like to assign a region ID to a group of adjacent zip codes and create a new set of points that is essentially the outside boundary of the combined region. Are there libraries out there in Python/Matlab/Javascript that have done something similar or do I need to read a book on discrete topology to do this?

Any relevant resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, please add an excerpt of this GeoJSON file in the question that shows its structure and relationships.